# Update files with awk to delete a pattern occuring within a multilined string

Tags: awk, sed

I want to process and modify several YAML files, using awk to update and delete the below input file.

Here is a sample input file:

```
    #Modify this
    sss:
      - ccc:
          brr: 'mmm'
          jdk: 'jdk8'
      - bbb:
          brr: 'rel/bbb'
          jdk: 'jdk8'
      - aaa:
          brr: 'rel/aaa'
          jdk: 'jdk7'


    #dont change me
    sss: ccc
    ppp: 'vvv'
    pname: 'vvv'
    brr: 'mmm'
    jdk: jdk8
    jdks:
      - jdk8
      - jdk7
    file:
      - test:
          exec: 'input'
```

Expected output once processed by the awk snippet below:

```
    #Modify this
    sss:
      - ddd:
          brr: 'mmm'
          jdk: 'jdk8'
      - ccc:
          brr: 'rel/ccc'
          jdk: 'jdk8'
      - bbb:
          brr: 'rel/bbb'
          jdk: 'jdk8'

    #dont change me
    sss: ccc
    ppp: 'vvv'
    pname: 'vvv'
    jdk: jdk8
    jdks:
      - jdk8
      - jdk7
    file:
      - test:
          exec: 'input'
```

Till now I already have an awk snippet which processes the first part of the input without any issue:

```
/sss:/ { sss = 1; }
/- ccc:/ { ccc = 1; i = substr($0, 1, index($0, "-")-1); next; }
$1 == "brr:" && $2 == "'mmm'" {
    if (sss && ccc) {
        print i "- ddd:";
        print i "    brr: 'mmm'";
        print i "    jdk: 'jdk8'";
        print i "- ccc:";
        print i "    brr: 'rel/ccc'";
        sss = 0; ccc = 0;
    }
    next;
}
{ print }
```

How to improve the above snippet to delete these lines:

```
    - aaa:
        brr: 'rel/aaa'
        jdk: 'jdk7'
        file: optional-line
```

and make sure that the does not update second part of the input where `brr: 'mmm'` the line gets deleted.

Comment: @askb: It is safe to assume only 2 lines to skip _after_ `- aaa:`? (or) the 2 lines after it would always be empty ?

Comment: @askb: That does not help! the question is how would you expect the end of the `- aaa:` can be reached, it needs a definitive pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^[[:space:]]*sss:[[:space:]]*$/ { print; inBlocks=1 }
inBlocks {
    if ( /^[[:space:]]*-/ ) {
        ++numBlocks
    }

    block[numBlocks,++blockNumLines[numBlocks]] = $0

    if ( !NF ) {
        blockNr = 1
        numLines = blockNumLines[blockNr]
        line = block[blockNr,1]
        sub(/[[:alpha:]]+/,"ddd",line)
        print line
        for (lineNr=2; lineNr<=numLines; lineNr++) {
            print block[blockNr,lineNr]
        }

        type = block[blockNr,1]
        gsub(/[^[:alpha:]]+/,"",type)
        sub(/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*$/,"\047rel/"type"\047",block[blockNr,2])

        for (blockNr=1; blockNr<numBlocks; blockNr++) {
            numLines = blockNumLines[blockNr]
            for (lineNr=1; lineNr<=numLines; lineNr++) {
                print block[blockNr,lineNr]
            }
        }
        inBlocks = 0
        numBlocks = 0
    }
}
!inBlocks
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
    #Modify this
    sss:
      - ddd:
          brr: 'mmm'
          jdk: 'jdk8'
      - ccc:
          brr: 'rel/ccc'
          jdk: 'jdk8'
      - bbb:
          brr: 'rel/bbb'
          jdk: 'jdk8'


    #dont change me
    sss: ccc
    ppp: 'vvv'
    pname: 'vvv'
    brr: 'mmm'
    jdk: jdk8
    jdks:
      - jdk8
      - jdk7
    file:
      - test:
          exec: 'input'
```